# Calculated measure working in Power Pivot but not in Power BI Preview Designer

Tags: office365, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular, powerbi

I am new to Power BI and I am suppose to build some dashboards using the Power BI Preview Designer. I have a data model in Tabular Model, and I am creating a data connection to the Power BI Preview report, I have some calculated measure which are working fine for me in Power Pivot and even in Power BI Q&A, but the same measure are not working showing the value in Power BI Preview Disgner, for percentage measures it either shows 0% or NaN(Not a number) although the format is set to Decimal Number.

If anyone also working on it and have same issue or you know the solution please help.

Regards,
Piyush

Comment: Can you please describe what you are trying to do?
The Power BI designer does not support creating of calculated measures yet, or are you trying to use the website to create reports?

Comment: Hi Kasper, I am not trying to create a new measure in Power BI Designer, the measures are already created in Tabular Model, I am simply dragging those measure to my report, but it doesn't working for me, the same model when I am uploading to power bi Q&A it works, it works in Power View and Power Pivot as well

Answer (score 0):

Having a same issue but instead of NaN getting 100%,check your measure calculation once